# Next select option that matches filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having issue trying to get the dropdown to cycle to the next option which has a data-completed=false

```
<select id="selectionChamp">
<optgroup label="1">
  <option data-completed=true selected>Text 1</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="2">
  <option data-completed=true>Text 2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="3">
  <option data-completed=true>Text 3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="45">
  <option data-completed=false>Text 4</option>
  <option data-completed=false>Text 5</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<input type="button" id="fieldNext" value="Next">
```

Javascript:

```
    $("#fieldNext").click(function() {
    var $selected = $("option:selected");
    var filter = "[data-completed!=true]";
    $selected.attr("data-completed", true).prop("selected", false);
    var $next = $selected.next("option"+ filter);
    if ($next.length === 0) {
      $next = $selected.parent("optgroup").next("optgroup:has(option"+ filter+")").find("option"+ filter+":first");
    }
    $next.prop("selected", true);
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/w9kcd/105/

I got it works when `filter = "";` but not when `filter = "[data-completed!=true]";`

It should start at 1 and go to 4 then 5, skipping 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next` method just selects the next immediate sibling of the element. If you pass a filter to it, it will select the next immediate sibling, only and only if it matches the specified selector. It doesn't go until it finds a matching element. The alternative method is `nextAll` which does this but the next target elements are not siblings of the starting element. You could start from the parent of the selected element and then use the `:has` selector for finding `optgroup`s that have the expected children but a better/more efficient option is:

```
var $options = $("#selectionChamp option");

$("#fieldNext").click(function() {
    var $selected = $("option:selected").attr("data-completed", 'true');
    // get the index of the current selected element
    var i = $options.index($selected);  
    // find the first next matching element
    // you can also pass a string to the filter method: `[data-completed!="true"]`
    var $next = $options.slice(i /* + 1 */).filter(function() {
        return this.getAttribute('data-completed') !== "true"; 
    }).eq(0).prop("selected", true);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahr73vvx/) you can find a demo on jsfiddle.net.